# mvc - First "get" result for request.params get exception, second "get" is ok

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, http-post, dangerous-request

mvc - First "get" result for request.params get exception, second "get" is ok.
i have a page that has a field with xml text in it.
i am using validation=false.
but, on post method in the controller i am trying to get the requset.params and i get an error of 
"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client". after some digging and debugging i see that first time i am trying to get the request.params i get an exception, BUT when i try to get it for the second time everything is ok.

this is the filter i am using to avoid problems with the xml (i am converting it to binary data and empty the xml string field):

```
   public class RestAPIAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
                 ((SimulationModel)filterContext.ActionParameters["model"]).Data = CommonConverters.StringToByteArray(((SimulationModel)filterContext.ActionParameters["model"]).StringData);
            ((SimulationModel)filterContext.ActionParameters["model"]).StringData = string.Empty;


            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

and this is the post method:

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [RestAPIAttribute]
    public ActionResult EditSimulation(Guid id, SimulationModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            model.RelationModel = new RelationModel(false, this.Resource("Simulations.AddToObjects"), "SimulationToObjects", id, sessionId, Request.Params, new List<ObjectTypes>() { ObjectTypes.Entity, ObjectTypes.EntityType, ObjectTypes.Universe });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }

        /* more code here*/

        return View(newModel);
    }
```

now, as you can see one of the RelationModel's constuctor has a parameter of request.param which is giving me the problem.

my currenty workaround for this issue is just calling it twice (but i am looking for better solution or at least an explanation):

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [RestAPIAttribute]
    public ActionResult EditSimulation(Guid id, SimulationModel model)
    {
        try
        {
             try
            {
                model.RelationModel = new RelationModel(false, this.Resource("Simulations.AddToObjects"), "SimulationToObjects", id, sessionId, Request.Params, new List<ObjectTypes>() { ObjectTypes.Entity, ObjectTypes.EntityType, ObjectTypes.Universe });
            }
            catch
            {
                model.RelationModel = new RelationModel(false, this.Resource("Simulations.AddToObjects"), "SimulationToObjects", id, sessionId, Request.Params, new List<ObjectTypes>() { ObjectTypes.Entity, ObjectTypes.EntityType, ObjectTypes.Universe });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
        }

        /* more code here*/

        return View(newModel);
    }
```

Comment: I had similar issues because my routes were wrong, make sure that you use @Content on your css and js imports in the layout, if your route is wrong it will hit /Home/Index/Content/css instead of /Content/css and you will see errors. And you see no errors when the path you are currently on is correct for all files, other times from other location you will see errors. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is ASP.NET MVC 3+ you could use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on your model property that contains the XML. This will disable request validation only for this property and not the entire request:

```
public class SimulationModel 
{ 
    [AllowHtml]
    public string StringData { get; set; } 
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditSimulation(Guid id, SimulationModel model)
{
    // you could directly use model.StringData here without any 
    // encoding needed

    return View(newModel);
}
```

And if this is an ASP.NET MVC 2 application running in ASP.NET 4.0 in addition to decorating your controller action with the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute you might need to put the following in your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

If it is an ASP.NET MVC 3 application you don't need to put this line in your web.config in order to use the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute.

Comment: problem remains. first time i get exception second time its ok.

Comment: Which version of the ASP.NET MVC framework are you using? And which version of ASP.NET? Did you remove any custom attributes from the action signature?

Comment: MVC 3 DotNet 4. i left only the [HttpPost] attribute

Comment: Did you decorate your model property containing the XML text with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute as shown in the first part of my answer?

Comment: yep, otherwise i would get an exception before i get to Post method.

Comment: Then this should work. Decorating the string property with the `[AllowHtml]` attribute allows you to pass XML data to it from the view. I notice that in your code you are manually using `Request.Params` but you should only be manipulating the view model which is safe.

Comment: is there any way making request params secure? i cant use the model in my case...

Comment: Why can't you use a view model? What's the point of using ASP.NET MVC if you are not taking advantage of all the features it offers? Things like automatic model binding, strong typing, ...

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to remove the xml string from the request params before i get to post method.

Comment: No, there is no way to remove it but even if that was possible that would be an absolutely horrible workaround to do.

Comment: because i am in a situation which i dont want to change the code of the previous developer who wrote it..

Comment: Change it don't worry. Changing bad code is always a good thing to do. I guess that the code that the previous developer wrote was not at all intended for ASP.NET MVC but some legacy WebForms application. So you have to take that into account.

Comment: OK, I thought I would be able to persuade you to follow good practices but I see that I am failing to do so. In this case I will provide you the solution but I really wanted to point it out so that other people having the same problem as you don't repeat the same mistake as you. So the solution is to have your POST controller action take a `FormCollection` parameter and then read from it instead of `Request.Params` => `fc["data"]` instead of `Request["data"]`.

Comment: Thanks! i'll try to implement the better solution, the thing is that i have some fileds that are being added dynamically while loading the page. thats why i cannot use then within a predefined model...

Comment: Well, you haven't actually explained what you mean by *dynamically adding fields to a view* but that are perfectly fine solutions using view models for that. Read here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: Please start a new thread if you need more updates. This one starts to get a little off.